# An unbiased 8-sided die (a d8) is rolled until an 8 appears uppermost. What is the probability that 15 rolls are required until an 8 first appears?

Tags: probability, dice

So far I have, $n=15, p = 1/5, k = 1.$
Don't know if that is correct. And then if it is, I have:
$$\frac{15!}{1!(15-1)!}\times (1/15)^1 \times (14/15)^{15-1} = 0.38\%$$

Is that correct?

Comment: Is it exactly fifteen rolls to get the first $8,$ or fifteen rolls or more to get an $8?$

Comment: This looks like the probability of rolling an $8$ exactly once at any time within $15$ rolls of a fair $15$-sided die.

Comment: It takes 15 rolls to get an 8

Answer (score 3):

Your calculation is not correct.  First you need the probability that you don't roll an $8$ on any of your first $14$ rolls.  That probability is $\left( \frac 78 \right)^{14}$.  Then you need the probability that your $15$th roll is an $8$.  That probability is $\frac 18$.  So your answer is $\frac{7^{14}}{8^{15}}$, which is approximately $1.93$%.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please use mathJax to format math on this site, as discussed at https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation.

I had trouble deciphering "p = 1/5 k = 1", and you did show work, so I'll just give you the answer.

Let $A$ denote the probability that the 1st 14 rolls are all 7 or less.  Let $B$ denote the probability of getting an 8 on the 15th roll.

Then the probability of both of these (independent) events occurring is $A \times B.$

$p(A) = \left(\frac{7}{8}\right)^{(14)}.$ 
$p(B) = \frac{1}{8}.$